# AOSP make build error on Android M _r46 tag

Tags: java, android, makefile, android-source

make build outputs this strange error when building Android M 6 (basic AOSP. branch: `android-6.0.1_r46`).

```
Error: out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/telephony-common_intermediates/classes.jar: unknown package name of class file ***/MyClass$1.class
```

**The same code builds perfectly fine with Android L 5.**

It seems to be an issue with anonymous classes inside the code (eg: this first issue is for a BroadcastReceiver).

For some reason the compiler cannot identify them or something.

Comment: I assume you added MyClass to AOSP?

Comment: What is `***/MyClass$1.class`?

Answer (score 0):

If the class path is actually expected to be in the public Android API, you can add it in `build/core/tasks/check_boot_jars/package_whitelist.txt`.